# Rails. Active Record. Odrer by associated table columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have three tables for my site:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :urls
  belongs_to :group, touch: true
end

class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

So I need to get Ulrs list which are in group1 sorted by their item name.

Similar question is how to get full list of Urls sorted by their Group name and then by Item name.

It is not a problem to create couple of simple loops with sort_by methods, but maybe there is any elegant way to do it without them? 
It seems that .where and .order methods don't support associations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Url.joins(item: :group).
  where(groups: {name: 'group1'}).
  order('groups.name ASC, items.name ASC')
```

Comment: very, very non-obvious syntax. I don't see any logic with these singular and plural forms in request.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: @MikhailChuprynski prular forms in `where` and `order` clauses is because table in DB is named this way. On the other hand, if you pass `Hash` to `joins` method, its keys and values should be equal to appropriate association names.